# TF-IDF Corpus Is it possible to use dispersion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, corpus, tf-idf

I am developing some software which aims to uniquely identify a web page, by performing TF-IDF (comparing with a general English corpus to remove common words). It took a while to find a good free corpus (http://www.wordfrequency.info/top5000.asp), however, this corpus only provides frequency and dispersion. It does not say how many documents were included in the corpus, so I can't work out the IDF table. It does include a dispersion value, which ranges from 0-1, with 1 indicating a word appears in every document.
Does anybody know of (or can figure out) a way to achieve a similar IDF table using this data?
Also, if anyone knows of a free corpus which includes the information I need it would be just as appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
IDF = log (Total Documents in Corpus/Total Documents containing the term)
```

If the dispersion is the fraction of documents containing a term, then: `log (1/dispersion)` would be the IDF

Comment: you wouldn't believe how much I face palmed when I realised this. Thanks anyway though